# How to pass Jenkins build parameter as arguments to dockerfile in declarative pipeline

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline. I am trying to pass Jenkins build parameters like jira_id and repository name along with credentials to the dockerfile as arguments.

However, on execution, the dockerfile is not able to receive any arguments as passed below.

May I please know the correct way of doing it?

**Jenkinsfile Stage**

```
stage('Create Image'){
                    steps{
                          script{
                          withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'admin', passwordVariable: 'admin_pw', usernameVariable: 'admin_user')]){
                          dir("${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/"){
                          def repo=docker.build("latest","--build-arg admin_user=$admin_user --build-arg admin_pw=$admin_pw --build-arg jira_id=$jira_id --build-arg repository_name=$repository_name --no-cache .")
                          }
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:8
RUN echo "$repository_name, $jira_id, $admin_user"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between using `ARG` and `ENV`.

`ARG` can be set during the image build with --build-arg and you can’t access them anymore once the image is built.

`ENV` values are accessible during the build, and afterwards once the container runs. You can set ENV values in your Dockerfile.

[image]

The Jenkinsfile stage is correct.

Changes in Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8
ENV jira_id=$jira_id
ENV repository_name=$repository_name
ENV admin_user=$admin_user
RUN echo "$repository_name, $jira_id, $admin_user"
```

Comment: In my case, I do not want to access them once the image is built. So, ARG is working fine. However, I have noted your explanation and it will help me in other cases.

Comment: What if I need to parameterize the FROM registry url:
For eg. I have 2 different registry to push the image and I need to parameterize registry to take the image 
FROM registry1:org-centos:latest
or 
FROM registry2:org-centos:latest?

Comment: @DeepeshRehi It is possible. Please create a new question.

Comment: I figured it out, and posted my answer as well!, let me know what you think about it.
If needed I will create a new question.

Comment: @DeepeshRehi There is a more better and easy way to achieve it using the `--build-arg` option to build the image

Comment: It would work for everything, apart from 1st line. Hence, the answer I posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In the dockerfile, I have to receive all the variables using ARG.
ARG jira_id=$jira_id

Answer (score 0):

While the above answers are correct, it fails if, you need dynamic naming in the "1st line" of Dockerfile i.e. if you have multiple repos to pull for same build it could look like this:

```
FROM $corp_repo/centos:8
```

To make it work, I used `sed` with ENV in a different way, define ENV outside Dockerfile in your jenkins stage using something like this:

`env.CORP_REPO = "${params.corp_repo}/centos:latest"`

My jenkins stage looks something like this:

```
    stage('Build docker') {
    daArtifactoryHelper.artifactoryDockerLogin(dockerArtifactoryAddress, artifactoryCredentialId)
    env.CORP_REPO = "${params.corp_repo}/centos:latest"
    sh 'sed -i "1c\$CORP_REPO" Dockerfile'
    sh "cat Dockerfile"
    sh "docker build -t ${fullImageName}:${version} ."
    sh "docker push ${fullImageName}:${version}"
}
```

Here, `sh 'sed -i "1c\$CORP_REPO" Dockerfile'` is replacing the First line with the dynamic repo name set using ENV.

You can play around with it.
Again, this works for nth number lines as you are defining scope outside your Dockerfile.

Cheers!