# Passing Jenkins Pipeline parameter to a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm getting a "Bad substitution" error when trying to pass a pipeline parameter to the Dockerfile.

[Jenkins parameter: version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRi3L.png)

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

            stage('Build in docker container') {
                agent { dockerfile true }
                    steps {
                        sh 'node -v'
                     }
            }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /root

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl wget vim nano zip git htop ncdu build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev apt-transport-https -y

# install node 10
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
#RUN node -v
#RUN npm -v

RUN echo ${params.version}

#ARG VERSION
#RUN echo $VERSION
```

Jenkins error message:
[Jenkins error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2mU.png)

I'm sure the problem is that im new to pipelines/docker. :)
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Post the content rather than the images

Comment: Hop this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884755/how-to-pass-jenkins-build-parameter-as-arguments-to-dockerfile-in-declarative-pi/63888678?r=SearchResults#63888678

Answer (score 1):

issue resolved by adding the ARG variable to the Dockerfile.

This is how the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /root

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl wget vim nano zip git htop ncdu build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev apt-transport-https -y

# install node 10
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
#RUN node -v
#RUN npm -v

ARG version=fisticuff
RUN echo $version
```

and this is how the Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build in docker container') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg version="$version"'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node -v'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output in Jenkins:
[Jenkins console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9i9l.png)

*Much obliged to all of you for giving me the hints. It helped me a lot!*

Answer (score -1):

Try running Dockerfile independently first.
Since you are new to docker try one step at a time.

Comment: i have no problem by creating the image or to build the container. that step is checked, it works fine.
btw, i know how to pass this parameter to a shell script but i need to know how to pass it to the dockerfile.

Comment: This can help https://forums.docker.com/t/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-in-dockerfile/14488

Comment: I tried Dockerfile above as-is and got this error.   => ERROR [7/7] RUN echo ${params.version}                                 0.5s
------
 > [7/7] RUN echo ${params.version}:
#10 0.474 /bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution